# Maps into products

Tags: general-topology, continuity

**Theorem**: Let $f:A\to X×Y$ be given by the equation

$$f(a)=((f_1(a),f_2(a)).$$

Then f is continuous if and only if the functions

$f_1:A\to X$ and $f_2:A\to Y$ are continuous.

how to prove $\Leftarrow$ this direction.I wanna prove like this if we take an open set in $X×Y$ then get an inverse image which is open in $A$.

Comment: Shouldn't domain of $f$ be $A$?

Comment: What is  the topology on $X \times Y$?

Comment: If you want to prove that inverse image of a set in $X \times Y$ is open in $A,$ then aren't you actually trying to prove $\Leftarrow?$

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy  product topology on $X×Y$.

Comment: @sahiba  Apologies, I edited

Comment: The forward direction follows from the fact that $f_i = \pi_i \circ f$ for $i=1,2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W$ is open in $X \times Y$ then there exist open sets $U_i$ in $X$, $V_i$ in $Y$ such that $W =\bigcup_i (U_i \times V_i)$. Now $f^{-1}[W]=\bigcup_i \left(f_1^{-1}[U_i] \cap f_2^{-1}[V_i]\right)$ which is open.